# Visual Studio: Same suite and version but different release

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Does it matter if different users are running the same suite of Visual Studio and version but with different releases, in context of working on a project?

For instance i am running VS 2015 Pro update 1, and some using VS 2015 Pro update 2 and rest using VS 2015 update 3?

As per my understanding, updates are released to incorporate bug fixes and performance enhancements, and it shouldn't impact the project behavior and solutions.

Comment: Does it matter in what context?

Comment: Not any specific context, just the day to day working on existing projects.